# Query table with all names in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I cannot alter and I am trying to wrap my head around an appropriate way to query this table in one statement based on one given value.

Roughly here's what the table looks like:

[image: Sample Table]

What I'm after is a way to query the table using only the SubBody code in order to get *all* names associated with it.

for example,

```
<query> where SubBody = '1001'
```

returns

```
| HName | HSName | BName | BSName   |
+-----------------------------------+
| Toys  | Sport  | Ball  | Baseball |
```

Comment: So - did you manage to solve your issue? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Head.Name as HName , 
       SubHead.Name as HSName , 
       Body.Name as BName , 
       SubBody.Name as BSName   
FROM yourTable as SubBody
JOIN yourTable as Body
  ON SubBody.Body = Body.Body
 AND Body.SubBody IS NULL
JOIN yourTable as SubHead
  ON Body.SubHead = SubHead.SubHead
 AND SubHead.Body IS NULL
JOIN yourTable as Head
  ON SubHead.Head = Head.Head
 AND Head.SubHead IS NULL
WHERE  SubBody.SubBody = '1001'
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can express the logic as joins, for some reason correlated subqueries come to mind first:

```
select (select th.name from t th where th.head = t.head and th.subhead is null) as hname,
       (select ts.name from t ts where ts.head = t.head and ts.subhead = t.subhead and t.body is null) as sname,
       (select tb.name from t tb where tb.head = t.head and tb.subhead = t.subhead and tb.body = t.body and tb.subbody is null) as bname,      
       t.name as bsname
from t 
where t.subbody = 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is close to what Juan Carlos has posted. Which one you like depends a bit on your style.

```
WITH BaseRecord AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM ToyTable
    WHERE SubBody = '1001'
)
SELECT 
    h.Name AS HName,
    hs.Name AS HSName,
    b.Name AS BName,
    bs.Name AS BSName
FROM BaseRecord bs
    INNER JOIN ToyTable b ON bs.Body = b.Body AND ISNULL(b.SubBody,'') = ''
    INNER JOIN ToyTable hs ON bs.SubHead = hs.SubHead AND ISNULL(hs.Body,'') = ''
    INNER JOIN ToyTable h ON bs.Head = h.Head AND ISNULL(h.SubHead,'') = ''
```

I'm not sure whether your "empty" cells contain nulls or empty strings. Either way, both are taken into account here.